# which language set for NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i am developing arabic and urdu app(in same application) so which language i set for NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute(in assemble info page).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A Visual Studio project will generally have:

- Neutral resource files (e.g. MyResources.resx) that are compiled into the main assembly (`MyAssembly.dll`)
- Culture-specific resource files (e.g. MyResources.de-DE.resx) that are compiled into a satellite assembly in a culture-specific subfolder (e.g. `de-DE/MyAssembly.Resources.dll`).

You should set NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute to the culture you are using in your neutral resource files.

If it's a global application, you will generally use "en-US" for the neutral resources, and put other languages in satellite assemblies, for consistency with the .NET Framework itself.

In your case, you say you're using two non-English languages, so just pick one of them.  Although your example image has English text, so you could use that too.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

[NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/10/11/479330.aspx)

You could set it to one of them, the one you would want to fall back to.