# "Language neutral" property in file's Details tab

Tags: c#, dll, localization, assemblies

How can I change language property of a DLL written in C#?

I tried to go into the `Project Properties -> Assembly Information -> Neutral Language` ComboBox and set it to `English (United States)`.

After I build/rebuild the project/solution, when I right-click on DLL and go to the Details tab, the Language property always says `Language Neutral.`

**EDIT:**
The solution I found is to use external *.res files (simply generated by Visual Studio), and then choose it in dialog `Project Propertie->Application Tab-> Resource File`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This property sets the [AssemblyCulture] attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.  The MSDN library article has this important note in the Remarks section:

> The attribute is used by compilers to distinguish between a main assembly and a satellite assembly. A main assembly contains code and the neutral culture's resources. A satellite assembly contains only resources for a particular culture, as in [assembly:AssemblyCultureAttribute("de")]. Putting this attribute on an assembly and using something other than the empty string ("") for the culture name will make this assembly look like a satellite assembly, rather than a main assembly that contains executable code. Labeling a traditional code library with this attribute will break it, because no other code will be able to find the library's entry points at runtime.

Another important restriction is that the GAC can distinguish assemblies by assembly name, version, architecture and public key token but not by culture.  Satellite assemblies must always be stored locally.

Long story short, *never* pick anything but Neutral on a project that contains code.  Satellite assemblies are almost always auto-generated from the resources in your project and automatically get the proper [AssemblyCulture] attribute.

Comment: thanks for answer, but is it possible in anyway to change the `Language property` in file's `Details Tab` (no matter why, imagine I have strongly reasons for that). My DLL will not have any string resources that are needed to be localized, I just want to change that `Language property`, that we can see in `Details tab` via explorer.

Comment: It ought to be quite clear from my answer why you cannot do this.  Sorry, I cannot "imagine" an alternative if you don't tell us why this is important to you.

Comment: I've understood your answer clearly, but wanted to know if are there any ways (including dirty) to change that property, despite of rules that used by GAC and others. Though I've found solution by myselt, your answer is clearly explain the usage of [AssemblyCulture] attribute, so I'll mark it as accepted, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*(Adding this answer as a supplement to [the answer by @Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12176658/1497596).)*

In your Assembly Information (accessed via Project Properties), when you change Neutral Language to "English (United States)," that causes this line to be added to `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US")]
```

However, note the following line in `AssemblyInfo.cs` remains unchanged:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

From this, it is clear that the Neutral Language setting is distinct from the Assembly Culture setting.

If you are localizing your application, you should set `NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute` to the culture you are using in your neutral resource files. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11411104/1497596) for more.)